# День недели по заданной дате на русском языке

Tags: php

Делаю так, но не работает. В чем проблема?

```
$day[0] = "Воскресенье"; 
$day[1] = "Понедельник"; 
$day[2] = "Вторник"; 
$day[3] = "Среда"; 
$day[4] = "Четверг"; 
$day[5] = "Пятница"; 
$day[6] = "Суббота"; 
$time = '2015-01-01';
$dnum = date("w", $time); 
$textday = $day[$dnum]; 
echo $textday;
```

Comment: добавьте `echo $dnum;`

Comment: @Igor но тогда выводится порядковый номер дня недели

Comment: `$dnum = intval(date("w", $time)); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$day[0] = "Воскресенье"; 
$day[1] = "Понедельник"; 
$day[2] = "Вторник"; 
$day[3] = "Среда"; 
$day[4] = "Четверг"; 
$day[5] = "Пятница"; 
$day[6] = "Суббота"; 
$time = '2015-01-01';
$dnum = date("w",strtotime($time)); 
$textday = $day[$dnum]; 
echo $textday;
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php date timestamp принимает а не строку.

Comment: PSR-2. В списке аргументов НЕ ДОЛЖНО быть пробела перед запятыми, но ДОЛЖЕН быть пробел после каждой запятой.